# Trigger method on user creaton

Tags: django

I'd like to trigger a method when a user is created through the admin panel but I can't find where I can do that. Any suggestion available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to restrict the triggering to the admin panel, you can use Django signals (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/)

Otherwise, you can override the `ModelAdmin.save_model` of the admin to trigger your function, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model